# MonoDevelop 2.8 , Xcode 3 and Lion

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, osx-lion

Now that MonoDevelop 2.8 has gone production, can we upgrade to Lion and keep Xcode 3.x with the separate Interface Builder?

After installing Lion, are there any items to update in the MonoTouch environment? We have the latest production Mono, MonoTouch and MonoDevelop installed as of Oct 5, the release date for MonoDeveloper 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Lion with Xcode 3, the old Interface Builder, Monodevelop 2.6 and Monotouch 4.2.2 without any issues. I've been running Monodevelop 2.8 beta in parallel for a while.
Xcode 4 is also installed, It all goes to separate folders.
So go ahead, upgrade if you feel like doing so.
If you're happy with Snow Leopard, stick with it. No need to change a running system.

Comment: I was hoping Lion would run faster. Did you experience any benefit upgrading to Lion?

Comment: All the animations make it in fact slower on my Macbook Pro (model 2009). But I wanted to install it because I was missing the feature to resize windows on any corner! :-)